# Remove auto-completed user/pass from browser

Tags: html, browser

OK so I have a login page. And the browsers put the username/password there, if I chose to save these credentials.

Problem is that inside the website, I have an "AddUser" view, and it also auto-completes there the user/pass fields.

Comment: this isn't related to `c#` nor `model-view-controller` as it is browser-behaviour

Comment: Your question is not clear so is the title, what are you exactly after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really up to the browser.  It doesn't happen on the server side.  You can politely ask the browser to not save data for autocomplete by adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your form tag.  Something like this:

```
<form id="frmLogin" action="/login/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

If you can't do that for some reason, you can use jQuery to add the attribute in code:

```
$('#frmLogin').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

If asking nicely isn't working, you can try to trick the browser:

```
<form id="frmLogin" action="/login/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div style="visibility:collapse;">
        <input type="password"/>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

The hidden `div` has a dummy password field which should come before the real password field.

Comment: The first one, with autocomplete="off", I've tried before and it didn't work. But the second one did work, you sneaky genius...